# Changing IP Address in terminal

Tags: ifconfig

I am trying to change my IP address using terminal commands.

When I use `ifconfig 10.10.10.134 netmask 255.255.255.0` I can change the IP address and can still connect to my network (I can ping other devices), but I can no longer connect to the internet. Is there something else I should be doing, or even a different command I should be using?

Comment: You'll need to give us more details about your network and why you want to change your IP, before we have any chance of giving helpful advice.  `ifconfig` should be enough, but you can also use `ip(8)`.

Comment: In particular, the routing table before and after might be informative.

Comment: What was your IP address and netmask previously (i.e. when you could connect to the rest of the Internet)? What is current output of `netstat -rn`?

Comment: This is probably a question to be referred to the guy who runs your firewall / NAT device.

Comment: `netstan -rn` gives me [this](http://imgur.com/APx9Y3V)

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @Henrik you can use `ifconfig`, but you should use the newer `ip` command from the `iproute2` package if it is available on your system (it will have the same effect).

```
ip addr add 10.10.10.134/24 dev <interface>
```

while `<interface>` is the interface where the IP shall be added

To be able to access the internet your routing must be setup correctly, normally those routes are handled by the **dhcp-client**. If you have a static IP, you have to setup the **default-gateway** manually.

You can check your routing table with:

```
ip route show
```

which will print out the routing table, and should look something like this:

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.2
```

In most circumstances the internet is accessed using a `default-gateway` entry:

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
```

while `default` stands for `0.0.0.0/0` matching any IP address. This will cause all traffic to be routed to the router with IP `10.0.2.2` if the target IP address is not matched by any of the more specific routes as shown in the example above.

To add a `default-gateway` enter:

```
ip route add default via <router-IP> dev <interface>
```

while

- `<router-IP>` is the IP address of the next gateway in your network
- `<interface>` is the interface where you are connected to the network

Now to use the **DNS** system you may also have to add `nameservers` manually.

In linux those are specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`, edit the file manually and add your nameservers, as shown in the example below with google nameservers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

or by simply entering:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I considered giving you -1 for misspelling my name :-(

Comment: @Henrik I am sorry for misspelling your name.