# change IP address

Tags: networking, command-line, terminal, ip, ifconfig

I tried to change my private IP address with the following commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 192.168.1.12
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up
```

They just work fine becouse the IP changes but then the newtork become unavailable. The issue remains if I change again the IP address to the initial one. What's wrong with that? How can I solve it?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289710/changing-ip-address-in-terminal .

Comment: This is also pertinent to IP address issues - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57710/static-ip-address-shifting-to-192-168-1-251?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

You might need to specify the subnet mask to use. The command above is likely assuming that the subnet mask is `255.255.255.255`, which is for a point-to-point network.

The following might work:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 192.168.1.12/255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up
```

(Also check to see that a default route is present, using the `ip route` command.)

On a side note, `ifconfig` is deprecated and is replaced by the `ip` command. The equivalent steps are:

```
sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 down
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.12/24 dev wlp3s0
sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 up
```